# Regular expression in php to find roman numerals

Tags: php, regex, roman-numerals

I use PHP to highlight all the *`roman`* numerals in string.

For example:

```
Protocol XXXIV/14 from session...

Protocol XXIX/13  from session...

Protocol XXXV/13  from session...
```

So I've found a perfect example on http://regexr.com/2uhln. It works good for above examples, but when I try to use it in php, it stops work.

My PHP code is

```
    $subject = "Protocol XXXV/13  from session...";
    $pattern ='/(?:XL|L|L?(?:IX|X{1,3}|X{0,3}(?:IX|IV|V|V?I{1,3})))/';
    preg_match($pattern,$subject,$matches);
```

It outputs just 1-3 characters from roman numeral, so

```
XXXIV - gives XXX

XXIX - gives XX

XXXV - gives XXX
```

I have two questions:

1. What is wrong? How to fix it?
2. how to modify regular expression from http://regexr.com/2uhln to work for all roman numerals up to one hundred (roman C). It doesnt work ex. XLVII, XLVI, XLV.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your pattern. That is, place the longest pattern as first, then medium finally short. syntax would be like `long|medium|short` . So that the longest string would be matched first.

```
$re = "~L?(?:X{0,3}(?:IX|IV|V|V?I{1,3})|IX|X{1,3})|XL|L~m";
$str = "Protocol XXXIV/14 from session...\nProtocol XXIX/13 from session...\nProtocol XXXV/13 from session...";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**Update:**

```
\b(?:X?L?(?:X{0,3}(?:IX|IV|V|V?I{1,3})|IX|X{1,3})|XL|L)\b
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aN2nU6/5)

Comment: OK, it works much better now (thank you), but still crusher with XLVI, XLV, XLVIII,XLIV (gives just X) and XXVI, XXVIII (gives just XXV) and XXXVI (gives XXXV)